# Why do I get a HelpSetException - NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run a Swing desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

The application and the help system runs ok from the netbeans IDE but when deployed the exception is returned on the help set. I have checked that the three help jars jh.har, jhall.jar and jhbasic.jar are in the project > Properties > Libraries > Compiling. I have checked the contents of the distribution created from the NetBeans and verified that the three help files are in the lib folder. I have checked and verified that the Windows 8.1 CLASSPATH includes:

```
    CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin; 
    D:\jh2.0\javahelp\lib; 
    D:\jh2.0\javahelp\bin
```

This is the dump from the run:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NewDawn4>java -jar Newdawn.jar
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/help/HelpSetException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.help.HelpSetException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Having researched this problem in depth and followed the recommendations of others, I am still without a solution and unable to see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting classpath in manifest:

```
 Class-Path: lib/jh.jar lib/jhall.jar lib/jhbasic.jar
```

Comment: Yes Krivo, that worked, thanks. There were a couple of other class missing errors that were returned after your suggested fix but I was able to fix these also in the manifest. Something seems to have changed in Netbeans that now requires one to explicitly manage the manifest file. I've never needed to do this before.